# Only rerender the affected child in list of components while state resides in parent React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a chat app, I have 3 components from parent to child in this hierarchical order: `Chat`, `ChatLine`, `EditMessage`.
I'm looping through `messages` state in `Chat` to display multiple `ChatLine` components as a list, and I pass some state to `ChatLine` and then to `EditMessage`.

I need the state :

```
const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState("");
const [editingId, setEditingId] = useState(null);
```

to remain in the parent component `Chat` so I can have access to it later there.

Anyway, now when I click on the `Edit` button, the `EditMessage` component shows a textarea, and I'm setting state onChange in it, but everytime I click the Edit button or type a letter in the textarea all the components rerender as I see in React DevTool Profiler, even the children that didn't get affected, I only need the `Chat` and affected `ChatLine` to rerender at most.

The whole code is available in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sun-uwlil), and deployed in [Netlify](https://csb-7zv6r.netlify.app/).

And here it is here also :

(Chat.js)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ChatLine from "./ChatLine";

const Chat = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState("");
  const [editingId, setEditingId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMessages([
      { id: 1, message: "Hello" },
      { id: 2, message: "Hi" },
      { id: 3, message: "Bye" },
      { id: 4, message: "Wait" },
      { id: 5, message: "No" },
      { id: 6, message: "Ok" },
    ]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>MESSAGES :</p>
      {messages.map((line) => (
        <ChatLine
          key={line.id}
          line={line}
          editValue={editValue}
          setEditValue={setEditValue}
          editingId={editingId}
          setEditingId={setEditingId}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

(ChatLine.js)

```
import EditMessage from "./EditMessage";
import { memo } from "react";

const ChatLine = ({
  line,
  editValue,
  setEditValue,
  editingId,
  setEditingId,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {editingId !== line.id ? (
        <>
          <span>{line.id}: </span>
          <span>{line.message}</span>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setEditingId(line.id);
              setEditValue(line.message);
            }}
          >
            EDIT
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <EditMessage
          editValue={editValue}
          setEditValue={setEditValue}
          setEditingId={setEditingId}
          editingId={editingId}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(ChatLine);
```

(EditMessage.js)

```
import { memo } from "react";

const EditMessage = ({ editValue, setEditValue, editingId, setEditingId }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        onKeyPress={(e) => {
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            // prevent textarea default behaviour (line break on Enter)
            e.preventDefault();
            // updating message in DB
            updateMessage(editValue, setEditValue, editingId, setEditingId);
          }
        }}
        onChange={(e) => setEditValue(e.target.value)}
        value={editValue}
        autoFocus
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setEditingId(null);
          setEditValue("");
        }}
      >
        CANCEL
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(EditMessage);

const updateMessage = (editValue, setEditValue, editingId, setEditingId) => {
  const message = editValue;
  const id = editingId;

  // resetting state as soon as we press Enter
  setEditValue("");
  setEditingId(null);

  // ajax call to update message in DB using `message` & `id` variables
  console.log("updating..");
};
```

Comment: Hi! For next time, please use the **on-site** facility for runnable React examples: Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). If you provide an on-site working example, it's markedly easier for people to show you a fix/solution. (Three reasons for it being **on-site**: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that **all** of the child components see their props change any time **any** of them is in the process of being edited, because you're passing the current editing information to all of the children. Instead, only pass the current editing text (`editValue`) to the component being edited, not to all the others.

`ChatLine` doesn't use `editValue` when it's not the instance being edited. So I'd do one of two things:

1. Use a different component for display (`ChatLine`) vs. edit (`ChatLineEdit`). Almost the entire body of `ChatLine` is different depending on whether that line is being edited or not anyway. Then only pass `editValue` to `ChatLineEdit`.
2. Pass `""` (or similar) as `editValue` to the one not being edited. In the `map` in `Chat`: `editValue={line.id === editingId ? editValue : ""}`.
3. Pass an "are equal" function into `memo` for `ChatLine` that doesn't care what the value of `editValue` is if `line.id !== editingId`. By default, `memo` does a shallow check of all props, but you can take control of that process by providing a function as the second argument. For instance:

   ```
   export default memo(ChatLine, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
       // "Equal" for rendering purposes?
       return (
           // Same chat line
           prevProps.line === nextProps.line &&
           // Same edit value setter (you can leave this out, setters from `useState` never change)
           prevProps.setEditValue === prevProps.setEditValue && // ***
           // Same editingId
           prevProps.editingId === prevProps.editingId &&
           // Same editingId setter (you can leave this out too)
           prevProps.setEditingId === prevProps.setEditingId && // ***
           (
               // Same edit value...
               prevProps.editValue === prevProps.editValue ||
               // OR, we don't care because we're not being edited
               nextProps.line.id !== nextProps.editingId
           )
       );
   });
   ```

   This is **fragile**, because it's easy to get the check wrong, but it's another option.

I would go for #1. Not even passing props to components that they don't need is (IMHO) the cleanest approach.

Comment: I'm already using memo in `ChatLine` & `EditMessage`, and `setEditValue` & `editValue` should also be available in the child component `EditMessage` so I can display it in the textarea or change the state value from there. If you can clarify more please.

Comment: @dwix - Sorry I missed those calls to `memo` in the export at the bottom of each module. (FWIW, I wouldn't hide it like that, just wrap it right away.) If the edit *value* goes to all child components, they they all have to re-render whenever it changes.

Comment: I understand. So to achieve the same result/behaviour of my app right now, what do you suggest I do to avoid the excessive rerendering problem? (While maybe keeping the state in parent)

Comment: @dwix - I don't see any reason for a `ChatLine` instance to receive the current `editValue` when it isn't being edited, only when it's being edited, so either A) Use a different component for display vs. edit (almost the entire body of `ChatLine` is different depending on that) and only pass `editValue` to the one being edited, or B) Pass `""` as `editValue` to the one not being edited. In the `map` in `Chat`: `editValue={line.id === editingId ? editValue : ""}`. But I would go for (A).

Comment: Ok I see, I'd actually go for the second option because I'll be adding a lot more content to `ChatLine` that won't be added to `EditMessage`. `EditMessage` will always be just a textarea with the `updateMessage` function.

Comment: @dwix - I'd make that a different component that both `ChatLine` and (say) `ChatLineEdit` reuse. But it's up to you. :-) (Sorry again for missing those `memo` calls.)

Comment: @dwix - FWIW, I thought of a third option I should point out, so I added it, but it doesn't change my recommendation. (Could be useful for other components, though.)